# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[EffectsRootModule -> InjectionToken ngrx/effects: NullInjectorError: No provider for Storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to migrate the Ionic application from Angular 10 to Angular 13. When upgraded to version 11, app works fine. When I upgrade it to Angular 12, the compilation is success but I get runtime error as shown below -

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[EffectsRootModule -> InjectionToken ngrx/effects: Root Effects -> AuthUserEffects -> AuthUserService -> HomePageGuardServiceGuard -> Storage -> Storage -> Storage]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Storage!
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMAqW.jpg)

HomePageGuardServiceGuard has storage defined as below -

`import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';`

`constructor( private router: Router, private storage: Storage ) { }`

Also IonicStorageModule is imported in corresponding module and declared under imports.

`import { IonicStorageModule } from "@ionic/storage";`

`imports: [..., IonicStorageModule.forRoot(), ....]`